# ajax result string changing

Tags: c#, ajax

I have the code below which i am running, i would like to move to another page once it is successful, tring to make the url in c# and when returned u can see the the string ic changed what can be done.

**C# Code**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string timeFinished()
{
  string url = "Summary.aspx?subjectid=" +   HttpContext.Current.Session["subjectid"].ToString() + "&chapterid=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["chapterid"].ToString();

  return url;
}
```

Returned from Ajax

```
 {"d":"Summary.aspx?subjectid=564\u0026chapterid=564
```

Ajax Java Scrpit

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "testchapter.aspx/timeFinished",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (result) {
                    //
                    window.location = result;
                }

            });
```

Comment: does using `&amp;` still returns char code instead of desired string?

Comment: where would i use this

Comment: changing `"&chapterid="` to `"&amp;chapterid="`

Comment: that may fix the & but it is still returnthe {d:"string"

Comment: it's not ideal, but being a json string you can use `window.location = result.d;` to use the link correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the resulting data is proper json, maybe you could try the following script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "testchapter.aspx/timeFinished",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json", // change to json here!
    success: function (result) {
        window.location = result.d; // result is a JS object; access the d property
    }
});
```